# angularjs with fullpage.js anchor and routing(complex)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, fullpage.js, anchor-scroll

I try to combine angularjs with fullpage.js on the index.page. Also, there are still some pages just rendered normally by route.

**Here is my route in app.js**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    // Below are all sections at index page
    .when('/#index', {
      controller: 'WelcomeCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/welcome/index.html'
    })
    .when('/#products', {
    })
    .when('/#learn', {
    })
    .when('/#help', {
    })
    .when('/#contact', {
    })

    // Other pages not using fullpage.js
    .when('/cases', {
      controller: 'CasesCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/welcome/cases/index.html'
    })
    .when('/users', {
      controller: 'UsersCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/users/login.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

However, when I scroll the sections at the index, each calls my first routes rule, then renders the index page though the section is been correctly scrolled to.

Besides, the route rules with hash tags seems not working when setting the html5Mode true, I got urls become http://xxx/%23products, how to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: this isn't going to work.  Angular (and most other SPA frameworks) use the `#` internally.  Angular will continue to use the hash for backward compatibility even with html5Mode enabled (which is why your urls are sanitized).  Angular provides a service `$anchorScroll` for cases where you must use traditional anchors in page content, but you can't combine `$anchorScroll` with another JS library (at least not to my knowledge).  You **definitely** can't use other JS libraries that expect the hash to be unaltered by angular.

Comment: @Claies, thank for your comment.
Actually, I haven't use $anchorScroll yet, because it normally binds with ng-click and $location.hash(); however, because the fullpage.js scroll the section with #xxx, I cannot just use click to resolve such problem.

Maybe what I need is add some route rule that can ignore the path like
"/#products". But I've tried to write that rule in "/##products, /\#products", both of them do not work...

Comment: I would certainly be interested to see if you come up with a solution, but from everything I know, there isn't a way to leave hash routes unaltered.  There have been many attempts, but no successes that I've ever heard about.

Comment: @Claies fullpage.js doesn't need the URL hash to work. Check out [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/noAnchor.html).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it by some hack.

First, I set the flag '**lockAnchors**' to be 'true' in fullpage.js.

Second, I set a controller to the navbar directive, which provides a **$scope.scrollTo(anchor)**, then after click and call scrollTo(anchor), I use **ngSilent** to silently change the url.

Finally, I check which page where I click the navbar. 
If not the index page with fullpage.js, I use **$location.path("/")** to back to the index, then silently add the anchor to the url, with using fullpage.js method to scroll to the anchor(after a timeout about 1200~1500).